# GNOME Desktop Dconf Settings Are Present Even Though Using Cinnnamon

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, cinnamon, dconf

I installed `cinnamon` on Arch. Everything works fine, but a little annoyance I am having is that there are still `org.gnome.dekstop` settings present. I removed `gnome-desktop`, which was installed as a dependency by `evince` (also removed). Are these settings normally present under `cinnamon` or is there some way to get rid of them? I dislike having the duplicates and I think this also led to a double lock issue where setting `disable-lock-screen` under `org.gnome.desktop.lockdown` fixed the issue. Is there a way to completely get rid of `gnome-desktop`?

Comment: Due to the fact cinnamon is based/derived on/from GNOME I think you cannot get rid of them.

Comment: Isn't it its own separate DE though. No longer an extension as of version 2?

Comment: have you tried to create a new user, to log in and to check if the org.gnome.* keys are still being created?

Comment: @AndreadePalo Yes after creating new user `org.gnome.desktop.*` keys are still there. I assume some `org.gnome.*` keys will remain as I have other gnome applications installed, just the duplicate desktop settings are annoying.